# render group by element in React component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
varcars=[{"type":"Color","data":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Red","optionName":"Color"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Yellow","optionName":"Color"}]},{"type":"Size","data":[{"Id":8,"Name":"S","optionName":"Size"},{"Id":11,"Name":"M","optionName":"Size"},{"Id":12,"Name":"L","optionName":"Size"},{"Id":13,"Name":"XL","optionName":"Size"}]}]
```

I am new in ReactJS. I have car object in React. Please suggest how can I print type and data value in React component.

Comment: iterate over variable and print it.

Comment: thanks its working fine